# Measurement Unit Conversion

Tags: c#, .net

My application needs measurement unit conversion build in. The unit conversion is based on user settings, not regional settings. The user just needs to define in what unit he wants his interface (C or F, Pa or Bar, ...)

Someone knows of a good (free) framerwork that provides this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) website has an article that describes a [Measurement Unit Conversion Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/Measurement_Conversion.aspx). Maybe that's something for you?